# Protecting sensitive information in Objective C source code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

If I have a password variable that is used for remote SSL authentication, is it secure to store in the source code?

e.g.

```
NSString * password =  @"password";
```

Are there better way?

**Update**: Sorry for confusion, I am **not** storing the user password, instead, I am storing a password that is used to call our own backend, all the app will use the same password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***My new answer:***

Try not to use static passwords to access the back-end, period.  What happens if somebody you don't want determines what that password is.  Why not use usernames & passwords?

You can also consider using a public key or embedded certificate to allow only your app access to the back end servers.

***My original answer:***

Sounds like you want to get to know the Keychain.

Here's a tutorial that talks about it:

http://maniacdev.com/2011/07/tutorial-how-to-use-the-ios-keychain-to-store-names-and-passwords/

And [here is a related question that talks about the security of Keychain under iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558252/ios-keychain-security).

You shouldn't have programs a store static password for all users, but instead have each user set up his/her account & password for authentication and then store ***that*** stuff in the keychain.

Comment: I have updated my question, I am not storing user password, instead, I am storing a password to call our backend, user don't know it.

Comment: It would have been nice if your original question was a bit more clear to begin with.  I've amended my answer.

Comment: Thanks! But even using a public key, is it easy to be detected by user, I am just thinking if there are better method to hide it some where in the code. I don't need to have a perfect way to do it, just better than storing as a string would be ok.

Comment: @Howard :I am also stuck up with the same issue .Did you find any way to  hide the string inside your code?

Answer (score 1):

Any text contained within your application is easily extractable. There's no real way around this - using the `strings` tool, anyone can see any and all text content statically embedded into your app. However, there are some ways around this - notably, if you split up your string into several static strings and concatenate in the right order, it will be much more difficult to reverse engineer the password contained in your app.

I recommend you take a look at a similar question ([How Safe is Information Contained within iPhone App Compiled Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919765/how-safe-is-information-contained-within-iphone-app-compiled-code/3919783#3919783)), and specifically, my answer to that question, for a more in-depth explanation of what I mean. (Nimrod's comment on that question is also interesting.)

Answer (score 0):

NO!

build your app. Go to the terminal and type `strings` and then drag your executable to terminal and press return... You'll see your *secret* password in plain text :)

You should store its hash.

Comment: I have drag the executable into the `strings` terminal but it keep loading, nothing can be seen..