# Using streaming radio URLs is legal to develop commercial apps?

Tags: android, iphone, audio-streaming, internet-radio

The simple question is: can we use audio streaming radio URLs (from the radio sites or shoutcast links or similar) to develop a little radio stream commercial application (iPhone or Android) ? Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a programming question. StackOverflow is not a law office. Please consult with qualified legal counsel for licensing questions.

Comment: I could suggest going here maybe to ask the question? http://answers.onstartups.com/ Not sure if it's the best place, but it's probably better than here.

Comment: +1, if you put the question in other way it will meet the Stackoverflow style: "how to write URL straming radio app", be a bit creative! :)

Comment: I'm very sorry, first "error" here, after 4 months :) in fact I hoped in great experience of developers here, to learn if was possible to develop a commercial radio app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First contact the radio station office, by phone or email an obtain a written "OK" from they.

Implementation:
For android is no problem. 
For iOS : at the Apple review you have to explain why is this more than a simple URL open, via browser. So you should add some platform feaures to be accepted.

Contacting they is not only for law, but they (should) know about you and maybe they will update they site with 2 link: download from Google Play or AppStore ( those 2 links)

If they know it is 15000 device is listening they, maybe they will upgrade the hardware too, bandwidth too.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I think the question is more about whether they are allowed to use the streaming URLs to develop their application, and not whether the marketplaces would allow the app. My guess is that some radio sites might be upset, while others might be excited for it. The asker should really consult the terms of service of the respective sites, and/or ask the sites themselves if it's allowed.

Comment: yes, you are right, and I have developed already an URL listening radio app, OFC I have asked the radio station office, but they response it was: "do anything what I want just don't ask money from they" :)

Comment: So the answer is: it depends from each radio station, but we are pretty sure that re-use of stream URL in app is NOT available for commercial use.

Comment: Some bigger radio stations even they change the port number to interrupt you from unpaid continuos listening, some smaller radio they are happy with free marketing. Like I told, first you have to contact they, after an OK response from they: at Android side is no problem, but at IOS you have to add some push notification or something platform dependent to be accepted as app

Comment: Thank you @matheszabi, I'll see that, in iTunes app store there are a lot of radio stream apps, NOT free, and I couldn't figure if the developer used public streams, or payed a fee, or other:)

Comment: @Huxley you are welcome, since there are many bad, illegal apps it doesn't mean it should be one more, I do prefer the clean way. See the updated response

Comment: @Huxley "couldn't figure if the developer used public streams, or payed a fee, or other" that can be checked: Buy they app and with a hexa viewer look into code (maybe you need a jailbreaked device or a special app to get the binary), for sure you will find the URL somewhere, Open the URL in browser and you got the response if is public or not. If is a 99 cent app, than the url is public 99.99% :)

Comment: Hehe @matheszabi, Im pretty sure that "Mum Apple" makes the .ipa package of iOS apps pratically impossible to control or look into, even with "hexa viewer" :)

Comment: Here is how to do it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914960/is-it-possible-for-an-app-to-be-decompiled